# windows for loop statement is failing in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am trying to copy a set of zip files through jenkins build. The same command works in `windows cmd line` but fails in `jenkins build`. The below is the command I am trying to execute

> for /r %i in (./*.zip)   do cp "%i" c:\temp

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the jar.zip located in jenkins workspace? If not use the absolute path to this zip file instead of relative path.

Comment: it is not about finding the files, but the error is syntax failure

Comment: C:\Jenkins\jobs\as\workspace\..\builds\2014-03-20_16-31-46\deploy\local\soa\cmn_ref 
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Jenkins\jobs\as\workspace>FOR /r x" C:\Jenkins\jobs\as\workspace\..\builds\2014-03-20_16-31-46\deploy\local\mds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"fails" how?

In all probability, you mean "fails to copy".

It's likely that you are using *nix replacement utilities, so you need to either ensure that `cp.exe` is on your path or use the `windows` utility `copy`, not `cp`.

Ah! the error is a syntax failure. Had you **edited-in** that extra information, even added such minor matters as the precise error-message, it would be easier to locate and advise.

In all probability, you need to use

```
for /r %%i in (./*.zip) do copy "%%i" c:\temp
```

but this is a guess in the absence of a complee error report.

Comment: Jenkins wraps those commands into a .bat file for execution. The .bat files require `%%i` syntax, like Magoo pointed out. The `%i` syntax only works on command line outside of .bat